# Wordress acf extended google maps field get lon/lat from a form in an email

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I got ACF form with Google Maps field. I retrieve data from a form via email.

ACf extended uses a placeholders for placing in an email. You can get the field value with

```
{field:map_field}
```

Which returns the address, i.e. `Unnamed Road, 72-100 Goleniów, Polska` or the exact adress, when it's named on map.

or

`{field:defibrylator_lokalizacja_mapa:false}` to get unformatted data as JSON:

```js
{
  "address": "Unnamed Road, 72-100 Goleniów, Polska",
  "lat": 53.552203584122466,
  "lng": 14.82477923813573,
  "zoom": 15,
  "place_id": "ChIJgwNS3SifAEcRFlyLx4z2hE4",
  "street_name": "Unnamed Road",
  "city": "Goleniów",
  "state": "Zachodniopomorskie",
  "post_code": "72-100",
  "country": "Polska",
  "country_short": "PL"
}
```

I want to get only `lat/lan` values. Tried almost the syntax from:
https://www.acf-extended.com/features/modules/dynamic-forms/form-cheatsheet
and can't get this key only.

Comment: I don't think any of these placeholder syntaxes are made to actually get a specific item out of a JSON value ... You might have to set up your own field formatter for something like this. https://www.acf-extended.com/features/modules/dynamic-forms/form-hooks#format-values